# Weight painting is causing weird extrusions

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

*Just wanna give a heads up that I'm new to this*

So I'm attempting to rig a mesh, however every time I attempt to weight paint it, it causes weird extrusions.

**What the model should look like**

[image: What the model should look like]

**What happens when I try to weight paint it**
[image: What happens when I try to weight paint it]

I have tried every possible option with the brush, stroke, falloff, etc. that I know of. If anyone knows what is causing this I would be very thankful. Also happy holidays.

Edit: So I apparently did not give enough info originally. I have been recommended to use blend exchange, which I now have. Yet again thank you for taking your time to help.

[image]

Comment: Upload your file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and add code to your Q to let us see your setup.

Comment: When a Blender User show a weight paint that is good.  It might be helpful for you to show more of the screen so we know what bone is selected.

Comment: Please show all modifiers on the body mesh in your picture.

Comment: what vertex group have you selected when painting?

Comment: @moonboots When painting I have one of the many bones selected. This appears to happen for all of them, no matter where I paint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

- Reset the pose of the armature in *Pose* mode (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>)
- Scale the mesh so that it fits the armature's new size
- Make the armature's bones fit the mesh (especially the legs)
- Scale up both the mesh and armature to make the parenting calculation easier (at least twice)
- Apply the scale of both the mesh and armature
- *Merge by Distance* the mesh in *Edit* mode to delete overlapping vertices
- Parent again

The weight will not be perfect yet, you'll still need to make some corrections

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a Mixamo action... i.e. Y up. Their weight paint to start with is not good. You can not this also in their screen animations - the moves are problematic, hands cross the leg etc'

When you import it into Blender, it's even worse.

You can either try to re-target with a paid addon (eg:AutoProRig). But you would still need to have a solid blender rig to be the target.

Then, their meshes are triangulated and not with quads like blender which makes the weight painting task more tedious and less intuitive.

But even with a very good rig and proper mesh it is nearly impossible to use this rig as is. You need additional bones or else the meshes will cross each other.

I would suggest to try it on a simpler object before.